# CGRectMake coordinates refers to which coordinates

Tags: ios

We use CGRectMake to set the width,height and x and y ordinates but x and y refers to which
 coordinates is of the root view and if yes then if I create an child view and then add this
 button to the child view then which coordinates it will refer to which coordinates?

```
UIButton *roundRectButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:

UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[roundRectButton setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 50, 200, 40)];
```

Comment: Alway refers to (direct) parent view. Be careful to understand the diff with bounds !

Comment: When you addSubview, subview is located at coordinates you set for its frame

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `frame`, it means you are positioning it with respect to its superview and when you use `bounds`, it means you are positioning it with the real (x,y) coordinates of device.

Here you are setting the frame of the **view**(i.e. UIButton) so you are positioning it with respect to its `parentView`.

Answer (score 0):

A UIView coordinates system refers to its superview and has its orignin in the top-left corner of its superview. 
As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

> The default coordinate system in UIKit has its origin in the top-left corner and has axes that extend down and to the right from the origin point. Coordinate values are represented using floating-point numbers, which allow for precise layout and positioning of content regardless of the underlying screen resolution. Figure 1-4 shows this coordinate system relative to the screen. In addition to the screen coordinate system, windows and views define their own local coordinate systems that allow you to specify coordinates relative to the view or window origin instead of relative to the screen.

So your uibutton coordinate system will refer to its super UIView.